# Flutter pushReplaceNamed is not working correctly

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, flutter-routes

I am struggling in my app:

After the user logs in I navigate to my `HomeView` with `pushReplaceNamed` , so the user should **not be able to pop** (by dragging) on the `HomeView` because in my thought it is the root view. However that is not the case.. Even after calling `pushReplaceNamed` the user can still drag to pop:

I simply call:

```
 Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
                          context,
                          Views.home,
                        );
```

On the first start of the App `StartView` is displayed, from there I navigate to `EmailView` and from there to `LoginView`. The code above is inside my `LoginView`. In all the other views I simply call `pushNamed`.

**What am I missing here? Why can the user drag pop on `HomeView`?**
(I know I can disable it with `WillPopScope`, but that does not feel right...)

This is my setup in my `MaterialApp`:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'AppFlug',
      navigatorKey: Get.key,
      theme: ThemeData(
        fontFamily: AppTextStyles.montserrat,
        primarySwatch: ColorService.createMaterialColor(
          AppColors.blue,
        ),
        backgroundColor: AppColors.white,
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: AppColors.white,
      ),
      initialRoute:
          AuthenticationService.isLoggedIn() ? Views.home : Views.start,
      onGenerateRoute: AppRouter.generateRoute,
    );
  }
```

And here is my `AppRouter`:

```
class AppRouter {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case Views.start:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const StartView(),
        );

      case Views.email:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => EmailView(),
        );

      case Views.signUp:
        String email = settings.arguments as String;
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => SignUpView(
            email: email,
          ),
        );

      case Views.login:
        String email = settings.arguments as String;
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => LoginView(
            email: email,
          ),
        );

      case Views.home:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => HomeView(),
        );

      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Text(
                'No route defined for ${settings.name}',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Omar I got it working: so `pushReplaceNamed` is only replacing the top most route. In my case all I had to do was call:

```
Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
  context,
  Views.home,
  (route) => false,
);
```

To quote the `doc`:

> To remove all the routes below the pushed route, use a [RoutePredicate] that always returns false (e.g. (Route route) => false).

Answer (score 1):

In your scenario, the user will be able to drag to pop and will return to `EmailView` cause you replaced login with home, this is what happens right? if u want to pop all of them (`StartView`, `EmailView`, `LoginView`) when you push to `HomeView`, then use:

```
Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, Views.Home, (route) => route.settings.name == '/')
```

Also, add this to your AppRouter Cases

```
MaterialPageRoute(
      settings: RouteSettings(name: /*name of the route*/),
      builder: (context) => ...
```

Comment: oh got it, so `pushReplaceNamed` is only replacing the top most route. In my case all I had to do was call: `Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                              context,
                              Views.home,
                              (route) => false,
                            );` because I wanted to remove all below routes